# How to use TikZ in a Picture environment way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, picture-mode

Now in paper for code I'm using `picture` environment for picture drawing. However it's not convenient since there's some fixed vector directions, which are hard to define for specific dot (if I want to put it on specific coordinate).

So I want to exchange `picture` with `tikz` images. But with `picture` I could manually put image by coordinate and with `\hangindent= \hangafter=` to put it anywhere.
Here is my example [image: Example. First picture needs to be changed] :

How can I do such good aligning with `tikz`? And **can** I do it?

**NOTE: ** I don't want to draw figures/images and then add this picture file to code. I want my pictures drawing with some package **inside my code**, as `picture` does.

**UPD:** some code for the picture below:

```latex
\hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-7
\begin{picture}(0,0)(-90,30)
    {
    \thicklines  % parallelogram block
    \put(5,30){\line(1,0){15}}
    \put(20,30){\line(3,-5){15}}
    \put(35,5){\line(-1,0){15}}
    \put(20,5){\line(-3,5){15}}
    }
    \multiput(20,30)(2, 0){2}{\line(1,0){1}}
    \multiput(35,30)(0, -2.5){10}{\line(0,-1){1}}   % from (1) to the bottom
    \put(24,30){\line(-6,-3){18}}
    \put(17,16.5){\circle*{1}}
    \put(16,17.5){\scriptsize $d$}
    \put(24.7,22.2){\circle*{1}}
    \put(26,21){\scriptsize $(2)$}
    \put(24,30){\circle*{1}}    % dot point for (1)
    \put(25,31){\scriptsize $(1)$}
    \put(20,10){\Huge $S$}
\end{picture}
```

Comment: I would utilize Mathcha :-) https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: @Sebastiano, not sure if I understand you or you understand me correct. I **don't want** to use third party files

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to draw the images. Sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano, ok maybe it was my fault since I didn't mention it in post. I'll correct it

Comment: you could use tikz but also look at pict2e package which extends picture to allow vectors specified by coordinate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks a lot. I tried to use next pipeline: Geogebra drawing --- PGF/TikZ code exportation --- paste it into the file --- use ```wrapfigure```. But it remains very hard and not working: there are some problems with PGF fonts --- it's very bold and image is bad. So I'll going to try ```pict2e``` package. Thanks!

Comment: A `tikzpicture` is just a box, so you should be able to use it exactly the same way. Maybe the baseline will be different by default, but you can adjust it with the `baseline` option.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's written and depicted in post

Comment: @JohnKormylo, for...? There is some code in question, there is an answer from me. You'd like to add something new/extra?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, check my edited answer for using ```wrapfig``` + ```pgfplots``` pipeline

Comment: Setting the picture size to zero is equivalent to the overlay option of tikz.  I believe tikz places (0,0) on the baseline in that case.  One can also achieve this effect using \raisebox and \rlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows how to use `\raisebox` and `\rlap` to overlap text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\unitlength=0.1cm
\raisebox{-30\unitlength}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\hspace{80\unitlength}%
\begin{picture}(35,32)(0,0)
    {
    \thicklines  % parallelogram block
    \put(5,30){\line(1,0){15}}
    \put(20,30){\line(3,-5){15}}
    \put(35,5){\line(-1,0){15}}
    \put(20,5){\line(-3,5){15}}
    }
    \multiput(20,30)(2, 0){2}{\line(1,0){1}}
    \multiput(35,30)(0, -2.5){10}{\line(0,-1){1}}   % from (1) to the bottom
    \put(24,30){\line(-6,-3){18}}
    \put(17,16.5){\circle*{1}}
    \put(16,17.5){\scriptsize $d$}
    \put(24.7,22.2){\circle*{1}}
    \put(26,21){\scriptsize $(2)$}
    \put(24,30){\circle*{1}}    % dot point for (1)
    \put(25,31){\scriptsize $(1)$}
    \put(20,10){\Huge $S$}
\end{picture}}}
\hangindent=-5cm \hangafter=-7
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This shows how to use the overlay and shift options of tikzpicture to position the image.  I added the scope so as to not confuse the positioning and scaling options.

I should add that I don't recommend either of these approaches, although it is good to know about them.  I like to use paracol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, xshift=3.5cm, yshift=-5cm]
  \begin{scope}[scale = 2,every node/.style={scale=1.25}, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm]
        \clip(1.8,-0.2) rectangle (5.2,3.3);
        \draw [thin] (3.,0.)-- (5.,0.);
        \draw [thin] (3.,0.)-- (2.,3.);
        \draw [thin] (5.,0.)-- (4.,3.);
        \draw [thin] (4.,3.)-- (2.,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (4.,3.)-- (4.6,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (4.6,3.)-- (4.401124147244972,1.7966275582650844);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (3.2,1.8)-- (3.4,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (3.2,1.8)-- (4.6,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (3.2,1.8)-- (4.401124147244972,1.7966275582650844);
        \draw (3.218331276016167,0.7871588640135541) node[anchor=north west] {\LARGE\textit{S}};
        \draw (3.0146418611448365,1.7990353120840399) node[anchor=north west] {d};
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \draw [fill=black] (4.133333333333333,2.6) circle (1pt);
            \draw[color=black] (3.9476707937812523,2.669643295001828) node {(2)};
            \draw [fill=black] (4.6,3) circle (1pt);
            \draw[color=black] (4.6835809378325095,3.109875256175351) node {(1)};
            \draw [fill=black] (3.2,1.8) circle (1pt);
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hangindent=-5.5cm \hangafter=-13
\sloppy
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]

Answer (score 2):

`wrapfigure` aligns in a similar way. Mainly for images, it supports `tikz` plots and graphs.

So the one way to do this is (though it's uses `pgfplots`, but I think behaviour for `tikz` plots is similar):

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2,every node/.style={scale=1.25}, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm]
        \clip(1.8,-0.2) rectangle (5.2,3.3);
        \draw [thin] (3.,0.)-- (5.,0.);
        \draw [thin] (3.,0.)-- (2.,3.);
        \draw [thin] (5.,0.)-- (4.,3.);
        \draw [thin] (4.,3.)-- (2.,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (4.,3.)-- (4.6,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (4.6,3.)-- (4.401124147244972,1.7966275582650844);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (3.2,1.8)-- (3.4,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (3.2,1.8)-- (4.6,3.);
        \draw [thin,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (3.2,1.8)-- (4.401124147244972,1.7966275582650844);
        \draw (3.218331276016167,0.7871588640135541) node[anchor=north west] {\LARGE\textit{S}};
        \draw (3.0146418611448365,1.7990353120840399) node[anchor=north west] {d};
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (4.133333333333333,2.6) circle (1pt);
            \draw[color=uuuuuu] (3.9476707937812523,2.669643295001828) node {(2)};
            \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (4.6,3) circle (1pt);
            \draw[color=uuuuuu] (4.6835809378325095,3.109875256175351) node {(1)};
            \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (3.2,1.8) circle (1pt);
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

So in the end it turns out to be this:
[image]

Comment: I was more curious about how you used picture than how to use wrapfig and tikz.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, ok, I'll insert some code in a question now